# Managing complex state, anything wrong with this approach?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My app UI state started to get somewhat complex with many useStates so I created a useStateMate hook (sorry for the cheesy name) as below. Any gotchas with this approach?

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const stateUpdater = (state, updater) => (property, value) => updater({ ...state, [property]: value })

export default function useStateMate(initialState) {
    const [state, updater] = useState(initialState);
    const setState = stateUpdater(state, updater);
    return [state, setState]
}
```

Usage: (UI state is managed by useStateMate, store data is not)

```
import React from 'react'
import useStateMate from './hooks/useStateMate'
import { useStore } from 'outstated'
import dataStore from './stores/mock-data-store'

const initialState = {
  selectedMarkerId: null,
  selectedDrivers: [],
  mapEditMode: { on: true, id: null, tool: null },
  quickChange: null,
  filter: '',
  groupBy: 'PostalCode,City',
  paths: new Map(),
  working: false
}

function App(props) {

  const [store, dispatch] = useStore(dataStore);
  const [state, setState] = useStateMate(initialState);

  const { selectedMarkerId, selectedDrivers, mapEditMode, quickChange, filter, groupBy, paths, working } = state;

 ...
```

Another approach I took was to useReducer but didn't like having to update state, compare:

```
dispatch({type: ..., value: ...})
```

with

```
setState('property', value)
```

Comment: it is better to ask it in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi. Thanks! will do.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use single `useState` and have a state as an object (*like we all had in those good old times of class components*). But if you follow this path it's better (*and also recommended by React folks*) to use [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) instead. Don't be confused by the naming here - it has nothing to do with Redux, although typical Redux reducers can be passed to `useReducer` as well.

> `useReducer` is usually preferable to `useState` when you have complex
>   state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state
>   depends on the previous one. `useReducer` also lets you optimize
>   performance for components that trigger deep updates.

Consider an example:

```
const initialState = {count: 0};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: state.count - 1};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter({initialState}) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'increment'})}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'decrement'})}>-</button>
    </>
  );
}
```